# System.UnexpectedException: Search unavailable thrown while deploying to prod

Tags: apex, unit-test, sosl

I am getting the following error while deploying to production: `System.UnexpectedException: Search unavailable` when executing a SOSL search within my test class at the line where I'm doing the following:

```
List<List<sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchquery);
```

My code where running well, prior to the Winter 16 release on my prod. What is strange is that my sandboxes are all Winter 16 versions, yet I'm not getting this error.

Does anyone know why? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: It's 2024 and this still can happen when running apex tests during a deployment. And also it can solve itself in a second attempt. Pretty weird

Answer (score 1):

This may be link to this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyUnAAK. Check this out.

Comment: The fact is that, the reported issue, is not the exact replica of my case, as in mine, im not returning multiple object in my sosl : String searchquery = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(name) + '\' IN ' + option1 + ' FIELDS RETURNING ' + objName + '(' + fieldlist + ')'; system.debug('## seacch query :' + searchquery); list<list<sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchquery)